# Voix passive et négation avec un adverbe modificateur

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, passif, négation

Comment peut-on traduire la phrase ci-après :

> The train has not been announced yet.

Est-ce que je dois la traduire par :

> - Le train n'a pas été encore annoncé,
> - Le train n'a été pas encore annoncé,
> - Le train n'a été encore annoncé,
> - Le train n'a encore été annoncé.

P.S. : Je n'avais pensé qu'aux deux premières phrases et, pendant que je les écrivais, les deux autres me sont venues à l'esprit !

Comment: "le train n'a pas été encore annoncé" (annoncé sans u). Je me suis permis de réécrire votre question dans un français plus usuel. N.B. : les remerciements par avance sont sous-entendus sur ce site

Comment: D'accord, mercii

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'ordre des mot habituel est

> Le train n'a pas encore été annoncé.

L'ordre des mots dans une phrase négative : sujet, « ne », verbe, particule(s) négative(s), compléments. Lorsque le verbe est composé, il n'y a que le premier auxiliaire après « ne » et les autres après la ou les particules négatives. Il est très rare qu'il y ait plus que le verbe ou le premier auxiliaire entre *ne* et *pas*, *plus*, *jamais*, etc.

> L'employé n'annonce pas (encore) le train.
>   Le train n'est pas (encore) annoncé.
>   Le train ne peut pas (encore) être annoncé.

Lorsque la seconde particule négative est qualifiée par un autre adverbe, ces deux mots sont groupé. Ici, « pas encore » forme un tout qu'on ne casse en principe pas.

> Le train ne peut pas déjà être annoncé.
>   Le train ne pourra jamais plus être annoncé.

On peut éventuellement repousser le mot *encore* après le verbe (« Le train n'a pas été encore annoncé. »), mais c'est un style littéraire désuet (et pas quelque chose qu'on écrirait dans la vie de tous les jours ou dans un exercice de grammaire).

Le mot *encore* peut être placé différemment, mais il change de sens. La phrase donnée ici est construite sur la locution « pas encore » (en anglais « *not yet* ») et signifie « il est trop tôt pour que le train soit annoncé ». La phrase suivante a un sens très différent :

> Le train n'a encore pas été annoncé.

Dans cette phrase, *encore* signifie que c'est un évènement répété (en anglais « *again* »), qui ici se trouve être négatif (en anglais « *again not* »). Voici des exemples de phrase positive :

> Le train a encore été annoncé avec dix minutes de retard.
>   L'employé a encore oublié d'annoncer le train.

Answer (score 3):

La formule [usuelle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas%20encore%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9,pas%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20encore&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1;,pas%20encore%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9;,c0;.t1;,pas%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20encore;,c0) est:

> Le train n'a pas encore été annoncé

Comment: Est la plus juste pour un devoir en class au lycée? :D

Comment: Au lycée et ailleurs, oui.

Comment: Mmh bien, "le train n'a pas été encore annoncé" n'est pas correct?

Comment: Ce n'est pas incorrect mais moins idiomatique.

Comment: D'accord, merci beaucoup!